# Adicionar dados em um unico Json

Tags: javascript, json

Olá

Estou com um problema e estou tendo grande dificuldade para resolver.. vamos la

Tenho 4 arquivos JSON exatamente iguais com 22 mil registros de produtos, mesmos parâmetros e tudo, a unica diferença entre eles é que cada um tem **um valor para estoque diferente** (são 4 lojas cada um com seu estoque)

Eu necessito de um **único JSON** com os **4 valores de estoque nele**, para assim conseguir implementar no meu sistema e utilizá-lo para retirar meus relatórios que tanto preciso

Exemplo

Eu tenho isso

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "nome": produto1,
    "valor": 20.0,
    "estoque": 5
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "nome": produto1,
    "valor": 20.0,
    "estoque": 2
},
{
    "id": 1,
    "nome": produto1,
    "valor": 20.0,
    "estoque": 3
}
```

E necessito disso

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "nome": produto1,
    "valor": 20.0,
    "estoque": 5,
    "estoque2": 2,
    "estoque3": 3
}
```

Alguém para dar uma Luz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se todos têm os mesmos arquivos a coisa é simples, só tens criar um loop e usar o index do loop para extrair os valores.

Um exemplo seria assim:

```js
const lojaA = [{
  "id": 1,
  "nome": 'produto1',
  "valor": 20.0,
  "estoque": 5
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "nome": 'produto2',
  "valor": 23.0,
  "estoque": 1
}];

const lojaB = [{
  "id": 1,
  "nome": 'produto1',
  "valor": 20.0,
  "estoque": 3
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "nome": 'produto2',
  "valor": 23.0,
  "estoque": 7
}];

const lojaC = [{
  "id": 1,
  "nome": 'produto1',
  "valor": 20.0,
  "estoque": 1
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "nome": 'produto2',
  "valor": 23.0,
  "estoque": 10
}];

const todos = lojaA.map((produto, index) => {
  return Object.assign(produto, {
    estoque2: lojaB[index].estoque,
    estoque3: lojaC[index].estoque
  }, {});
});

console.log(todos);
```